# open window without titlebar 

Tags: javascript

When the link is clicked it opens a new window:

```
<html>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
   function open_new_window(URL)
   {
   NewWindow = window.open(URL,"_blank","toolbar=no,menubar=0,status=0,copyhistory=0,scrollbars=yes,resizable=1,location=0,Width=1500,Height=760") ;
   NewWindow.location = URL;
   }
 </script>
<a href="#" onClick="open_new_window('http://www.google.com');">google search</a>

</body>
</html>
```

but how do I make that window small and make it appear without a titlebar?

After the window is opened, when the user clicks outside the window the window must be automatically closed. How can I do that?

Comment: How about putting the window in a frame and implementing an onClick for closing this frame, by clicking on the other frame.

Comment: @Adithya Surampudi how to put a window in a frame and close it when clicked outside??

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it's possible to do that with a real browser window, but you could get a similar effect by showing a `<div>` overlayed over the rest of the page. You could then have the "dialog" dismissed if the user clicks outside it. Take a look at [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) for a start.

Comment: how to make that dialog disapper when clicked outside that dialog.(i mean to close that dialog automatically). it should also not have that Close button at the top of dialog biox. how to do this???

Answer (score 0):

You can't hide the titlebar, but with Javascript events, you can make it close when it loses focus.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onblur=function() {
  window.close();
}
</script>
```

Note: Some browsers disable the JavaScript close function. However, if it was your JavaScript code that opened the window, it should work.